# Android broadcast event of microphone

Tags: android, microphone

Hello dear Android experts.

I have a simple question: is there any broadcast event I can listen when microphone detects a sound?
Or, if NO (the preambula of the question) is there a way to run ordinary service as long as user need. We have a microphone class which check periodically microphone activity, it runs in service, but Android OS kills it about hour.

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: Hi Ajmal, unfortunately no ...